# Way to closely examine Outlook rules on Exchange server side

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-web-app

Users in my organization complain about undelivered mail very often. 80% of times the reason are misconfigured rules on user's Outlook. Is there any way to closely examine Outlook rules on server side without loggin in to user's workstation with user's account? I found the command

`Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $user | Select-Object MailboxOwnerID,Name,Description,Enabled,RedirectTo, MoveToFolder,ForwardTo | Export-CSV C:tempInboxRule.csv -NoTypeInformation`

But it doesn't show full information about Outlook rule. I found [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-inboxrule?view=exchange-ps) But I do not see options such as `MoveToFolder` there.

Also I tried to grand myself Full permission on user's mailbox and log in via OWA and check the rules. But some rules are grayed out there and I can not check it's settings.

Also I tried to connect user's mailbox to my local Outlook, but rules seems not to sync.

My Exchange version is 2010.

Comment: If you just type, `Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $user` don't you get a list of all rules for the user? Then `Get-InboxRule –Mailbox $user -Identity {IdentityNumber}` to get info for each rule.

Comment: No, the result of `Get-InboxRule –Mailbox $user -Identity {IdentityNumber}` is very limited (1 line actually). It says that rule is enabled and says that priority is 1. No mo information!

Comment: First command, `Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $user` results?

Comment: Result of `Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $user` is list of rules with the following columns: Name, Enabled, Priority, RuleIdentity. Actually if I run second command `Get-InboxRule –Mailbox $user -Identity {IdentityNumber}` I get THE SAME, but only for 1 rule - the one that I written in `{IdentityNumber}` parameter.

Comment: Try `Get-InboxRule –Mailbox $user -Identity {IdentityNumber} | fl`

Comment: That was it! You can post it in answer section.What is this redirection to `fl`? Why doesn't it show full information from pure command?

Comment: This does not really belong here, but `ft` is short for Format-Table, which outputs a **table** with one item per line. `fl` formats the output as a list of properties in which each property appears on a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussed in comments, `Get-InboxRule –Mailbox $user -Identity {IdentityNumber} | fl` was able to give the expected result. `fl` stands for format list, you can also try `ft` format table. They apply to many powershell commands for formatting the result.

You can also use it inside a `foreach` loop to get all your users' rules.

I suppose it's a minimalistic approach, to not show full command result without extra parametres. It happens in many powershell commands.

Answer (score 1):

As **Krackout** said, you could use `fl` and `foreach` to output the details of all inbox rules. The following commands are for your reference:

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -ResultSize unlimited
foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes){Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $mailbox.Name | fl MailboxOwnerID,Name,Description,Enabled,RedirectTo, MoveToFolder,ForwardTo}
```

Comment: thanx for adding the full `foreach` command, I got lazy and didn't post it.